# In-App Billing Titanium android is giving :IAB_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am implementing In-App billing using `ti.inappbilling` module in titanium. Everything working fine i am getting purchase confirmation email on my registered email address but instead of returning `InAppBilling.RESULT_OK` response code it is returning `InAppBilling.IAB_RESULT_UNKNOWN_ERROR` response. I am testing with real products defined in play store app and app is also in beta version.

Can anyone please help me out to get success response and resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following things are done.

1. The app is published.
2. The account your are using to test is listed in beta tester list.
3. You accept to be tester in that account.
4. Created product is active.

Also after adding the product it takes a while to take effect. In my case it took two days although it was active.